# how to destroyed model in viewer immediately

Tags: c#, asp.net, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

currently I'm working on forge IDA, as of now my code is working very fine, I'm able to destroy & display model on viewer.
work flow is that, If I click on button first time it will get file from bucket, translate to svf then display it on viewer & for next button click it will first destroyed previous model then display next model on viewer.

it take around 45 to 60 sec to get file from bucket, translate to svf then display it on viewer

code to show and destroy model is written in viewer.js file.

but both the functions show model and destroy model is execute after Button1_Click event.

I want to destroy model on execution of line no 12   make the viewer blank till next model is displayed(i.e. till execution of line 14 to 18).

what will be solution to destroy model at line no.13 on web page, rather than destroying after completion of line no 20(i.e. after completion of Button1_Click() event)
any reply is appreciated.
thank you

```
 #default.aspx.cs
1.protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
2.{
3.    if (counter == 1)
4.    {
5.        ///////////////
6.        // code to get file from bucket and translate file to svf
7.        ////////////////
8.        //to display model on viewer
9.        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowModel", string.Format("<script>showModel('{0}');</script>", objectIdBase64));
10.    }
11.    else
11.    {
12.        //to destroy model on viewer
13.        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "destroyModel", string.Format("<script>destroyModel('{0}');</script>", objectIdBase64));
14.        ///////////////
15.        // code to get file from bucket and translate file to svf
16.        ////////////////
17.        //to display model on viewer
18.        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowModel", string.Format("<script>showModel('{0}');</script>", objectIdBase64));
19.    }
20.}

#viewer.js
function showModel(urn) {
    var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        getAccessToken: getForgeToken
    };
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
        viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'));
        viewer.start();
        var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;
        Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS['If-Modified-Since'] = "Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT"
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
    });
}
function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
    var defaultModel = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
    viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, defaultModel);
}
function onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
    console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
}
function destroyModel() {
    viewer.finish();
    viewer = null;
    Autodesk.Viewing.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To unload the currently loaded models, we can call `viewer.impl.unloadCurrentModel()` instead.

To unload a specific model, we can call `viewer.impl.unloadModel( model )`

```js
let model = viewer.getAllModels()[1];

viewer.impl.unloadModel( model );
```